# How to display data by the current system date

Tags: oracle

I have tried this, but it's not working:

```
SELECT day FROM table
 WHERE (SYSDATE - day) *24 < 0.5;
```

How can I get data in my database with its current date?

Comment: What does not work? What did you get? What did you want to get?

Comment: For example I had this column:                                                                                        Date:   May-26-2014                                                                                                 May-27-2014                                                                                          I just want to display data which has the current system date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `day` is a `date` column, why not do:

```
select day
from table
where trunc(day) = trunc(sysdate);
```